# How to create a custom shape for a Button

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-xml, android-shape

How to create a custom shape for a Button? Can I set different colors to button background colors for many conditions.Any help will be appreciated.Thanks.[image]

Comment: You can use this png as background of button and can use tint property to change color of background image

Comment: make nine patch image  for this shape

Comment: look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26162158/5241603

Comment: @ Kamran Ahmed Khan, How can I use for tint method for to change background image

Comment: @HtooAungHlaing, check the answer, I posted man

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/32291407/5239819

Answer (score 3):

> How to create a custom shape for a Button?

Create a `test.xml` file in drawable and add code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item android:id="@+id/one">       //<---- id is must for color change
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <size
            android:width="150dp"
            android:height="40dp" />
        <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
        <corners android:radius="10dp"/> //<---- remove radius if not needed
    </shape>
</item>

<item
    android:top="10dp"
    android:bottom="-12dp"
    android:left="-55dp"
    android:width="75dp">
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="-47">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
        </shape>
    </rotate>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

In button:

```
     <Button
        .....
        android:background="@drawable/test"
        ...../>
```

> Output

[image]

> Can I set different colors to button background colors for many conditions?

Yes, you can change at run-time. For that you have to assign id to each item to know where you want to make changes. As I did on my answer code.

```
LayerDrawable layerDrawable = (LayerDrawable) ContextCompat.getDrawable(Your_Activity.this, R.drawable.your_shape_test);
GradientDrawable gradientDrawable = (GradientDrawable) layerDrawable.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.id_of_drawable-one);
gradientDrawable.setColor(your_color);
```

Comment: it seems to be work in DesignView, but when i really run on device, it cannot get the real result

Comment: @HtooAungHlaing, Ok i didn't face this, let me see my code again.

Comment: Thanks @W4R10CK, for your help

Comment: @HtooAungHlaing, I'm not sure why its not working for you. I have added same layout on my app also. See the output image from real device.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

[image]

```
public class ButtonBackGroundDrawable extends Drawable {
private Paint paint;

public ButtonBackGroundDrawable() {
    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
}

@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {

    int height = getBounds().height();
    int width = getBounds().width();
    RectF rect = new RectF(0.0f, 0.0f, width, height);
    Point point0_draw = new Point(0, 0);
    Point point1_draw = new Point(width, 0);
    Point point2_draw = new Point(width, height);
    Point point3_draw = new Point(0, height);
    Point point4_draw = new Point(width / 10, height / 2);

    Path path = new Path();
    path.moveTo(point0_draw.x, point0_draw.y);
    path.lineTo(point1_draw.x, point1_draw.y);
    path.lineTo(point2_draw.x, point2_draw.y);
    path.lineTo(point3_draw.x, point3_draw.y);
    path.lineTo(point4_draw.x, point4_draw.y);
    path.lineTo(point0_draw.x, point0_draw.y);
    path.close();
    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    paint.setColor(Color.CYAN);
 //        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
}

@Override
public void setAlpha(int alpha) {
    paint.setAlpha(alpha);
}

@Override
public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter colorFilter) {
    paint.setColorFilter(colorFilter);
}

@Override
public int getOpacity() {
    return PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If you want to change the width change w/10 to your value. and accept my answer if you saved time.

Comment: yes, width is OK, add setColor method for custom color set and already accepted that one is mine ,Thanks